# How to make font showing glyph based on vowels?

Tags: fonts

Here's a Mongolian font [Link](http://hkuri.cneas.tohoku.ac.jp/project1/resources/css/fontface/opentype/MongolianUniversalWhite.ttf).

In Mongolian, if a word **only contains the vowel i**, it's considered feminine and the consonant g at the **end of the word** should have the feminine form [image], rather than the masculine form [image].

For example, the word *bicig* (BA I CHA I GA, code points +182A +1822 +1834 +1822 +182D) only contains the vowel i, and the word-final g should have the feminine form. But the font renders it in the masculine form.

For this font to render this word correctly, the sequence "BA I CHA I GA **FVS2**" (+182A +1822 +1834 +1822 +182D **+180C**) is needed. But the common practice for Mongolian font designing is to embed the harmonic rules in fonts rather than controlling it with control characters while typing. This font has encoded other harmonic rules but left this one unspecified.

This is a problem. Most texts that we can find on the web concerning bicig is simply +182A +1822 +1834 +1822 +182D, with no FVS2. This is actually true generally that the consonant form (feminine vs. masculine) is automatically detected in words, without typing any FVS. FVS is mainly for unusual shapes. Another font example would be [Onon Sonin Sans](https://font.onon.cn/assets/FontPack/OnonSoninSans.zip). It renders +182A +1822 +1834 +1822 +182D correctly but an additional FVS2 would render it incorrectly.

I tried to open the font in FontForge but didn't know where to start. Having watched a few instruction videos doesn't help since those solely illustrate how to edit a glyph for a single code point, with no mention of conditional rendering based on other elements in the word.

Is there a way to manually modify the font to correct for this wrong rendering?

Comment: Does it render correctly when you use the correct sequence (182D 180C)?

Comment: @Ouroborus It renders correctly using +182D +180C, but it’s not the correct sequence. This font has encoded other  harmonic rules but left this one unspecified. The common practice for Mongolian font designing is to embed the harmonic rules in fonts rather than controlling it with control characters while typing.

Comment: Are you sure? Is it the font that does that or the application? (Can you point to another font that is unicode compliant and works as you desire?) As near as I can tell, this looks correct as far as unicode is concerned.

Comment: @Ouroborus Yes I'm sure. The problem is that most text that we can find on the web is simply  +182A +1822 +1834 +1822 +182D, with no FVS2. This is actually true generally that the consonant form (feminine vs. masculine) is automatically detected in words, without typing any FVS. FVS is mainly for unusually shapes. Another font example would be http://font.onon.cn/assets/FontPack/OnonSoninSans.zip. It renders +182A +1822 +1834 +1822 +182D correctly but an additional FVS2 would render it incorrectly.

Comment: Alright. So there are two solutions. Get the author to fix the font or fix it yourself. There's software available for editing fonts.

Comment: @Ouroborus Right, this is exactly what I'm asking here, how to fix the font manually, aka myself.

Comment: Unicode encoding of Mongolian script has been problematic and is likely to undergo some changes. Within China, their standards body has also been working on revising the GB/T 25914 specification for Mongolian encoding. You might be interested in this resource---looking for reviewers! https://github.com/lianghai/mongolian/blob/main/utn/draft-utn-20201113.pdf